# TOAD invalid identifier error ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl

I need to help about the error code ORA-00904. I created the table by this code

```
CREATE TABLE OYKUN_EMPLOYEE(
EMPNO INTEGER,
EMP_NAME OYKUN_NAME_TYPE,
EMP_ADDRESS OYKUN_ADDRESS_TYPE,
EMP_BIRTH_DATE DATE,
EMP_DEPARTMENT OYKUN_DEPARTMENT_TYPE,
EMP_MANAGER OYKUN_MANAGER_TYPE,
EMP_SALARY OYKUN_SALARY_TYPE
)
NESTED TABLE EMP_NAME STORE AS OYKUN_EMPNAME
NESTED TABLE EMP_ADDRESS STORE AS OYKUN_EMPADDRESS
NESTED TABLE EMP_DEPARTMENT STORE AS OYKUN_EMPDEPARTMENT
NESTED TABLE EMP_MANAGER STORE AS OYKUN_EMPMANAGER
NESTED TABLE EMP_SALARY STORE AS OYKUN_EMPSALARY;
```

After i created the table i want to insert some data with code below

```
INSERT INTO OYKUN_EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDRESS,EMP_BIRTH_DATE,EMP_DEPARTMENT,EMP_MANAGER,EMP_SALARY) VALUES 
(100,
EMP_NAME (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','12/31/2017','Ted Mosby')),
EMP_ADDRESS (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','12/31/2017','Manhattan,New York')),
'5/20/1982',
EMP_DEPARTMENT (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','12/31/2017','Architect')),
EMP_MANAGER (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','12/31/2017','Walter White')),
EMP_SALARY (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_NUMBER('TO_DATE(1/1/2007)','TO_DATE(12/31/2017)',2500))
);
```

i tried every possible way but i still get "EMP_SALARY": invalid identifier.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Tables and columns are created successfully.

I also created type for the tables.

here,

```
CREATE TYPE OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR AS OBJECT (
VT_LB DATE,
VT_UB DATE,
VALUE VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TYPE OYKUN_TEMPORAL_NUMBER AS OBJECT (
VT_LB DATE,
VT_UB DATE,
VALUE_PART INTEGER
);

CREATE TYPE OYKUN_NAME_TYPE AS TABLE OF OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;
CREATE TYPE OYKUN_ADDRESS_TYPE AS TABLE OF OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;
CREATE TYPE OYKUN_MANAGER_TYPE AS TABLE OF OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;
CREATE TYPE OYKUN_DEPARTMENT_TYPE AS TABLE OF OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;
CREATE TYPE OYKUN_SALARY_TYPE AS TABLE OF OYKUN_TEMPORAL_NUMBER;
```

Comment: Presumably all these strings like `'1/1/2007'` should be dates like `date '2007-01-01'`. I'm not sure what the intention is with `'TO_DATE(1/1/2007)'` in the last line though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indicate the data type You are trying to insert, meaning that for example instead of:

```
`EMP_NAME (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','12/31/2017','Ted Mosby')),
```

You should have:

```
OYKUN_NAME_TYPE(OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','31/12/2017','Ted Mosby')),
```

So the whole insert would be like:

```
INSERT INTO OYKUN_EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDRESS,EMP_BIRTH_DATE,EMP_DEPARTMENT,EMP_MANAGER,EMP_SALARY) VALUES 
(100,
OYKUN_NAME_TYPE(OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','31/12/2017','Ted Mosby')),
OYKUN_ADDRESS_TYPE (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','31/12/2017','Manhattan,New York')),
'20/5/1982',
OYKUN_DEPARTMENT_TYPE (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','31/12/2017','Architect')),
OYKUN_MANAGER_TYPE (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('1/1/2007','31/12/2017','Walter White')),
OYKUN_SALARY_TYPE (OYKUN_TEMPORAL_NUMBER('1/1/2007','31/12/2017',2500))
);
```

PS. I changed date format compared to yours as I had different NLS settings

Comment: how am i going to write select query if the situation like below. I could not manage to do it.

Comment: I wrote SELECT EMPNAME.VALUE FROM OYKUN_EMPLOYEE but it gives error

Comment: @OykunYenal Try this notation:  `SELECT t2.value
FROM OYKUN_EMPLOYEE t1, table(t1.EMP_NAME) t2` or `SELECT (select value from table(t1.EMP_NAME))
FROM OYKUN_EMPLOYEE t1`

Comment: can u give me an example about the update and delete query i tried update i did but its not satisfies my demands.

Comment: I need to update EMPMANAGER but the old value must be remain i must add new tuple and change their valid times